# Parsing smv files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, model-checking

I download nusmv-tools(https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/nusmv-tools/) which is a model checker.
I installed it and its dependencies(such as xtext)on eclipse successfully and restart eclipse.

Now, I expect eclipse recognize the nusmv files (which extensions are '.smv'), however it cannot.

My question is, what should I do in order to make parse nusmv files in eclipse, so that eclipse will recognize and highlight the nusmv file(.smv).

(Should I create an xtext project or java project or general project?
Which libraries or external jars should I add to the project?)

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually, for nusmv, the problem was: I was using eclipse 64 bit, but it seems the nusmv-tools require to use 32 bits eclipse and xtext 2.5 version...
After downgrading the eclipse and xtext it worked for me...